# changing route of component to particular component if there is any change in routing

Tags: typescript, angular6

I want to change the routing of my application to a particular component when there is any change in routing take place in application. i am using **router.events** but it ended up in hitting lot of apis. Here is my code

```
 this.router.events.subscribe (event => 
    { if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
             this.reportService.getReport(this.reportId).subscribe(data => { 
                  this.Version = data.Version;
                     if(this.version <=5) {                        

           this.route.navigate['anycomponentroute'];
}
        }

    });
```

any solution??

Comment: hi, could you please elaborate a little more? what do you mean by "hitting a lot of apis"? you can paste the whole snippet if necessary

Comment: actually i am hitting some end points based on this condition and this started hitting it in loop

Comment: so, paste the class since it's too abroad the question

Comment: you can check the code